# FSharp.TypeProviders.Templates nuget for Type Provider development

Tags: f#, nuget-package, type-providers

I want to develop Type Provider.

Following [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/type-providers/creating-a-type-provider#a-simple-type-provider) you need to use [FSharp.TypeProviders.SDK](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.SDK).

[FSharp.TypeProviders.StarterPack nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.TypeProviders.StarterPack/) is deprecated, you need to use [FSharp.TypeProviders.Templates](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.TypeProviders.Templates/) instead.

So I created F# library project and added this nuget.

But I get the following error:

> Package 'FSharp.TypeProviders.Templates 5.2.0' has a package type
>   'Template' that is not supported by project 'fsharplib'.

I tried different F# libraries: Standard, Core or Full Framework with the same result.

How I can use FSharp.TypeProviders.Templates for building Type Provider?

Comment: From some of your earlier questions, it seems like you're just getting started with F#. I would really recommend getting more experience with F# before trying to tackle type providers, one of the most complex constructs in the whole language.

Comment: @rmunn, I would, but I'm interested in TP right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FSharp.TypeProviders.Templates is not a library package, it's a `dotnet` template: you use it to create a type provider solution.

To install it, run this in a console: `dotnet new -i FSharp.TypeProviders.Templates`

Then, to create a type provider solution, run: `dotnet new typeprovider -o <project_name>`

Unfortunately nuget.org doesn't recognize these types of packages, so it gives incorrect instructions.

Comment: `dotnet` project templates are different from VS project templates. But I agree that it's weird that they don't have a UI in VS to instantiate `dotnet` templates.